# How to call functions/methods inside objects in python

Tags: python

Here is my code.

How do I execute the print_point line? **Edited to work. Thank you**

```
class Point:
    def __init__(self, x=0, y=0):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    def distance_from_origin(self):
        return ((self.x **2) + (self.y **2)) **.5
    def print_point(p):
        print '(%s, %s)' % (str(p.x), str(p.y))
```

Here is what I type into the shell after running module:

```
p = Point(5,2)

p.x

    5

p.y

    2

p.distance_from_origin()

    5.385164807134504

p.print_point(p)

    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<pyshell#196>", line 1, in <module>
    p.print_point(p)
    TypeError: print_point() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)
```

Comment: You got `self` right in `distance_from_origin`, but not `print_point`. (Also, check your indentation: the `def`s should be indented.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `self` as the first argument or `print_point`. You'll also need to reference `x` and `y` using the `self` prefix because those fields belong to the instance.

```
def print_point(self):
     print '(%s, %s)' % (str(self.x), str(self.y))
```

Comment: What does `str(p, self.x)` mean? Actually, in his code `p` played the role of `self`.

Answer (score 2):

It's not clear what you want, since you've got the indentation wrong. Is `print_point` part of the class?

If so, you got `self` right in `distance_from_origin`, but perhaps not in `print_point`:

```
def print_point(self):
    print '(%f, %f)' % (self.x, self.y)
```

It is legal, **but a bad idea**, to use a different name for the `self` parameter such as your `p`.

(And note that the very act of printing will do the `str` conversion for you...)

Or did you want `print_point` to be out of the class, in which case you should have it as is but with `(p.x, p.y)`? Or, as suggested by other answers, a [static](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#staticmethod) or [class](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#classmethod) method?

Comment: Yes this is what I wanted. Thanks. I also typed commas instead of periods which made it harder. p,y instead of p.y.

Comment: Actually, in the original code `p` played the role of `self`.

Answer (score 0):

You used `self` as a parameter in the function `distance_from_origin`.

But you chose `p` as a parameter in the function `print_point`.

Actually, it works with `p`:

```
>>> p = Point(5,2)
>>> p.print_point()
(5, 2)
```

But there is a convention to use `self` for passing the instance of the class to the method. Otherwise everything gets very cumbersome.

Also, `%s` converts the object to string using `str` method. So, there is no need to convert in manually to string.

Taking it all into account, the function `print_point` will look like:

```
def print_point(self):
    print '(%s, %s)' % (self.x, self.y)
```

Point coordinates are represented by numbers so you may want to use special method for number output.

There is a new `format` method for string. It definitely [exists in Python 2.7](http://docs.python.org/library/string.html#format-examples). Just look at the examples and choose the most satisfactory output format for your case. For example you may do this:

```
def print_point(self):
    print('({self.x}, {self.y})'.format(self=self))
```